# fetch API or XMLHTTPRequest: How to get exact error reason for a network error?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, fetch

How to retrieve exact information about a network error? Chrome browser prints things like "net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" or "net::ERR_CERT_INVALID" into console but how can I retrieve them via JS? Is that possible to get them at all? Currently I use fetch API but I can switch to XMLHTTPRequest easily.

I need that to handle such errors to inform a user and let him know what does he need to do.

Comment: The fetch API use promises so you can easily get the errors with `.catch()`. It is what you are looking for ?

Comment: Nope. The error doesn't contain any specific information. It just says "TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Comment: You want to check the response status. The invalid cert for example should be a 400 series. Take a look at [`wretch`](https://github.com/elbywan/wretch) wrapper for `fetch()`. Will simplify this for you

Comment: I don't want to check response status. I want to check "reason of failed request", where failed request doesn't have any code.

Comment: @charlietfl — It won't be a 400 because it will error at the TLS level not the HTTP level.

Answer (score 4):

This information is intentionally inaccessible from JavaScript to prevent security issues.

Here is a Chromium bug report requesting this functionality in May 2017:  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=718447

Answer (score -3):

you can get the exact error as follow:

```
     fetch('url',
        {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({data})
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            //handle here or in catch
         })
        .then(function(json){
            console.log("succeed json re");
        });
```

You'll get resolved response once your promise has been resolved.

**Response.status** will give you status code. 
**Response.statusText** will give you exact error description as ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. which will be in case of errors and then **response.ok** will be false.

For more info: [FETCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: "Response.statusText — A string (default value "OK"), which corresponds to the HTTP **status code message**." 
1. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT doesn't have any status code as I know.
2. When ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT happens, fetch API throws an error which means there is no way to get Response instance and read **statusText** property.